# Is there a way to set Dragon Naturally Speaking 11 to dictate to an unfocused application?

Tags: focus, dictating

Does anyone know of a way in which to instruct Dragon to remain focused on a designated application regardless of its focus status instead of following focus changes? The primary use case we have is for doing multiple things at once, however if dragon follows a change in focus, then it becomes mostly useless.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with programming? IF so, please specify, else this belongs on superuser.

Comment: This may require scripting of some kind to override the default behavior of the program if it does not do this by default. It is up in the air where it belongs without knowing this. I have posted it here and on SU since I am not sure which is more applicable.

Comment: Yes, it is a programming question. The answer is - it depends. While I believe in free flow of knowledge, I was helped by the consultant from Dragon community and his solution was app specific and not to be published. It is one of those things where I would either recommend getting a consultant/freelancer who knows Dragon in and out or experiment until you understand inner workings of windows events flow and Dragon's intricate use of it. Well, I tried for a months until asking for help. Your mileage may very.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Dragon NaturallySpeaking does not support dictating background programs, only the active window.

Comment: While this is a correct statement, I think it is a wrong answer. Yes, only active window will receive the dictation inflow. However, Dragon control can be registered with a text box that goes into background while its active window is set to something else. It is hackish and tricky and will not work with all applications but should be possible.

Comment: If you can provide more details, then please post it as an answer and I'm sure @Elliot will change the accepted answer - I know I'll definitely vote it up, I'd be interested to know how to do it.

Comment: I am not at liberty to post the solution here as I did not develop it and neither do I own the code. Just hinting towards the possible approach (the part I was able to figure out myself), but could not orchestrate events. Unfortunately, every application has different requirements and the soltuion really depends on what "other things" people need to do while dictating. E.g. it would not be possible to type into one text box while dictating into another - nor it makes any sense. It should be possible to use, e.g. google maps or file diff. Sorry I can't be more helpful - hence a comment.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see your comment on the question stating that before. Thanks for pointing people in the right direction and for clarifying why it's difficult.